# environment variable undefined defined at top

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables

I have many functions that run uses the same header for api calls so I used a variable and assigned the headers at the top.

However, it's returning undefined for the accesskey and my program is crashing. So I just console logged the access key as well like `process.env.ACCESS_KEY`, and I'm getting the key. How do I properly assign it to the headers object as well so that it doesn't return undefined?

```
import axios from 'axios';

const headers = {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  AccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
};

const createMan = async (name: string) => {
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    Name: name,
  });
  const resp = await axios.post('https://example.com', body, {
    headers,
  });
  console.log(headers)//AcccessKey is undefined in the headers object
  console.log(process.env.ACCESS_KEY) //shows the access key. How?
  
  return id;
};
```

Comment: it must be assigned else where but it doesn't automatically update the `headers` object.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get you @DanielA.White. You mean `const headers` maybe assigned elsewhere? or the `access_key`?

Comment: `process.env.ACCESS_KEY`

Comment: use `dotenv` package and import it in your main or server.js file so by doing that you can access all the environment variables in your application

Comment: It sounds like `process.env.ACCESS_KEY` gets added to `process.env` (which [is modifiable](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processenv)) *later*, in other code not shown, rather than being set by Node.js when the process starts. So that other code should update `headers` as well (or you could make `AccessKey` an accessor property: `get AccessKey() { return process.env.ACCESS_KEY; }`).

Comment: What if you `console.log(process.env.ACCESS_KEY)` just before `const headers` ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how do I make it access like that inside the `const headers`?

Comment: @JeremyThille If i `console.log(process.env.ACCESS_KEY)` before the headers then there's nothing in the console

Comment: See? That's the problem, it's undefined at the beginning and gets defined at some point later, in some part of code you haven't shown here

Comment: This kind of question. at least you should try to use debugger step by step to check the values to see how the headers changes along the way. Then, you may spot the line of code cause the issue easily.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't assign it anywhere else in the code. It's just assigned at const headers at the top

Comment: @kibakoriasu - You literally replace `AccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY` with what I showed you above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder your solution worked, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `process.env.ACCESS_KEY` gets added to `process.env` (which is modifiable) later, in other code not shown, rather than being set by Node.js when the process starts. Three ways to address this:

1. Make that other code update `headers` as well.
2. Make `AccessKey` an accessor property that retrieves from `process.env.ACCESS_KEY` every time it's used:

   ```
   const headers = {
       Accept: "application/json",
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       get AccessKey() { return process.env.ACCESS_KEY; })
   };
   ```
3. Have a module that both A) Gets the access key (however it is that `process.env.ACCESS_KEY` is being assigned to) and B)  creates and exports an Axios instance. (More below.)

I would use #1 or #3 if possible, but #2 will work as well *if* the `process.env.ACCESS_KEY` value has been populated before `AccessKey` is used.

More on #3:

Axios has a useful feature where you can create an *instance* of it preconfigured with modified defaults, so you don't have to specify those defaults on every call. It looks like this (from [the documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance)):

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://some-domain.com/api/",
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {"X-Custom-Header": "foobar"}
});
```

So in whatever code you currently have that's setting `process.env.ACCESS_KEY`, you might do this:

```
const accessKey = codeThatGetsTheAccessKey();
export const myAxios = axios.create({
    headers: {
       Accept: "application/json",
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       AccessKey: accessKey,
    }
});
```

Then, you'd import that Axios instance (rather than using the global instance) and use it

```
import { myAxios } from "./your-module.js";

const createMan = async (name: string) => {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
        Name: name,
    });
    const resp = await myAxios.post("https://example.com", body);
    return id; // ??? I'm not sure where this came from
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have many calls which use the same header so you can set the header value for once, no need to send headers in each call.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['AccessKey'] = process.env.ACCESS_KEY;
```

if you're not getting value from your environment variables so use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

App.js

```
require('dotenv').config() // import at the top
```